# Crm2011 Get realtionship names in an early bound context

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using the early bound context created from crmSvcUtil and in my code, I create new entities, and I also have to link them together. The way I do it is by using the `context.AddLink(Entity source, Relationship relationship, Entity target)` function. The problem with that, is that I have to create a new relationship object, using the relationship name in the constructor as a string. What I would like, is a way to get that relationship name, instead of writing it in my constructor by hand.

Is it something that can be done ?

Comment: Do any of the properties of the entities give you the strings you need to build the relationship name? Perhaps [LogicalName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entity.logicalname.aspx)?

Comment: Why do you have to link them together?  you can just query the data at run-time to get related records.